# Issue cloning github repository with Username/Password

Tags: git, github

I have a python script where I have the command -

`REMOTE_URL = "https://" + USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD + "@stashurl.com/stash/scm/repo.git"`

I am currently getting the error -

```
stderr: 'fatal: unable to access  'https://name@gmail.com:Password@stashurl.com/stash/scm/repo.git/': Port number ended with 'P''
```

I believe the error is with the @ symbol in my email address, but I am not sure how to get around this issue.  I invesigated API tokens, but it looks like Stash doesnt have that feature (and I cant install the plugin to do this).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git is interpreting the `@` in the email address as the end of the credential pair. You should be building the following command up:

```
git clone https://name%40gmail.com@stashurl.com/username/repository.git
```

Replacing the `@` in the email address with `%40`